# Can't solve MultipleBagFetchException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting `MultipleBagFetchException` error. I tried to follow this tutorial, but it didn't helped me. https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/

I have an entity `Commodity` (simplified)

```java
@Entity
public class Commodity {
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients; // Embeddable

    @ManyToMany
    private List<CommodityType> commodityTypes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "commodity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "localizedId.locale")
    private Map<Locale, LocalizedCommodity> localizations;
}
```

I want to load `Commodity` with `ingredients` and `commodityTypes` loaded.

That's my repository:

```java
public interface CommodityRepository extends JpaRepository<Commodity, Long> {
    @Query("select e.id from Commodity e")
    List<Long> findAllIds(Pageable pageable);

    @QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = "hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough", value = "false"), forCounting = false)
    @Query("select distinct c from Commodity c left join fetch c.ingredients left join fetch c.localizations where c.id in :ids")
    List<Commodity> findAllByIdIn(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);

    @QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = "hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough", value = "false"), forCounting = false)
    @Query("select distinct c from Commodity c left join fetch c.commodityTypes t where c in :com")
    List<Commodity> findWithCommodityTypes(@Param("com") List<Commodity> com);

    default List<Commodity> findAllFullyLoaded(Pageable pageable) {
        return findWithCommodityTypes(findAllByIdIn((findAllIds(pageable))));
    }
}
```

After `findWithCommodityTypes` call, `Commodity` i got is not filled with `c.ingredients` and `c.localizations`. I'm getting `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role Commodity.localizations` error.

How do i get `Commodity` with `c.ingredients`, `c.localizations` and `c.commodityTypes`?

Comment: Do you get a MultipleBagFetchException or the LazyInitializationException?

Comment: If i use this query
`select distinct c from Commodity c left join fetch c.ingredients left join fetch c.localizations left join fetch c.ingredients where c.id in :ids`
i get `MultipleBagFetchException`

Comment: Cannot select more than one `List` at a time. Use `Set`. Many comments about this on the internet. Perhaps some website like stackoverflow has some.

Comment: Using `Set` is not a fix. Proper solution is to use several queries.
That's from tutorial. `So, if we have 50 post rows associated with 20 post_comment and 10 tag rows, the final result set will contain 10_000 records (e.g., 50 x 20 x 10), as illustrated by the following test case:`

Comment: Why do you use a List when you don't use OrderBy. Use a Set

Comment: `Set` of `Commodity`, `CommodityType` or `Ingredient`?